# Get the MD5 value of an S3 file using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, header, md5

In order to get a particular file from S3, I use, the script shown below:

```
# Get the configuration file
outputfilecfg=XXXX
amzFilecfg=XXXX
bucket=XXXX
resource="/${bucket}/${amzFilecfg}"
contentType="text/plain"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSigncfg="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=$S3_KEY
s3Secret=$S3_SECRET
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSigncfg} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`

curl  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
      -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
      -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
      -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
      https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${amzFilecfg} -o $outputfilecfg
```

Now I want to be able to get the value of 
the object metadata as specified by the S3 docs(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html). I want to be able to do this exclusively through curl and not the aws-cli. Is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible as they say that the meta data can be retrieved through the REST API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get just the object metadata by making a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request. To make a `HEAD` request in cURL, use the `-I` option.

```
curl  -I -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
      -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
      -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
      -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
      https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${amzFilecfg} -o $outputfilecfg
```

For more details about either of these, see

- S3 documentation for the [`HEAD Object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) API
- [cURL manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)